# How does Anton figure out that this person was one of the baddies?

Tags: night-watch-cycle, sergei-lukyanenko, last-watch

In *Last Watch*, how does Anton figure out after the attack in the Samarkand Chaikhana that Edgar was the inquisitor in league with the Dark and Light magicians going after Merlin's hidden artefact?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anton did NOT actually figure out that Edgar was the inquisitor part of the triplet right after the attack (attempted poisoning) in Chaikhana.

He realized it was Edgar after Edgar called him on a cell phone during the drive through the mountains, and right after hanging up, someone magically destroyed a mountain (suspected earthquake spell) near them. Alisher said that they missed, and Anton realized that the reason for the miss was that he just swapped his cell phone's regular SIM card for magic-ed up SIM card that Geser gave him.

That was when Anton **suspected** Edgar.

> То ли воронка проклятия, нанесенная на местность. То ли какое-то специальное заклинание, вызывающее землетрясение. Не знаю. Но сомневаться в том, что катастрофа имела магическую природу, не приходилось.
>   - Промазали, - сказал Алишер. - Антон... ты с Эдгаром разговаривал?
>   - Да.
>   - Уверен, что у Инквизиции нет к тебе претензий?
>   Я сглотнул вставший в горле комок. Претензии Инквизиции - это очень, очень печально. Не лучшая новость.
>   - Инквизиция бы не промазала... - начал я. Осекся. Достал мобильный телефон, посмотрел сквозь Сумрак.
>   В коконе из пластика, металла и кремния пульсировала синим огнем сим-карта. Типичное поведение для работающего амулета.
>   - Кажется, я знаю, что произошло, - сказал я, набирая номер. - Кажется, Инквизиция здесь ни при чем.

As usual, all translations are mine based on Russian book, NOT from English books.

> Could be the funnel of ineferno curse applied to the area. Could be a special Earthquake-causing spell. I do not know. But there was no doubt of the catastrophe's magical nature.
>   "Missed" - said Alisher. - "Anton ... were you talking to Edgar?"
>   "Yes."
>   "Are you sure Inquisition has no claims against you?"
>   I swallowed the lump which arose in my throat. Claims from the Inquisition are a very, very sad thing. Not the best of news.
>   "The Inquisition would not have missed ..." - I began. Then stopped. I took out the cell phone, and looked it over through the Twilight.
>   A blue-lighted SIM card was pulsating inside the cocoon of plastic, metal and silicon. Typical behavior of an active amulet.
>   "I think I know what happened" - said I, dialing the number. - "It seems that the Inquisition is not involved here".

Anton became **sure** when he asked Geser to transfer his call to European Inquisition office and they said that they didn't send Edgar to Samarkand (contrary to Edgar telling Anton that the office sent him).

> – Честно говоря, никогда не знал его фамилии, – признался я. – Бывший сотрудник московского Дневного Дозора, перешел в Инквизицию после процесса Игоря Теплова в Праге…
>   – Да, да, да, – оживился Эрик. – Эдгар. Конечно же. Нет, мы его не направляли в Самарканд.
>   – А кого направили?
>   – Не знаю, в курсе ли вы, Антон, – с нескрываемой иронией произнес Эрик, – но европейское бюро Инквизиции занимается Европой. И еще Россией в силу двойственности ее географического положения. Брать под свой контроль происшествия в Азии, где расположена страна Узбекистан, у нас нет ни сил, ни желания. Вам надо связаться с азиатским бюро Инквизиции. Сейчас оно расположено в Пекине. Вам подсказать номер?
>   – Нет, спасибо, – ответил я. – А где сейчас находится Эдгар?
>   – В отпуске. Уже… – последовала короткая пауза, – месяц. Что-то еще?
>   – **Маленький совет, – не удержался я. – Проверьте, где находился Инквизитор Эдгар во время известных вам эдинбургских событий.**
>   – Подождите, Антон! – Эрик утратил невозмутимость. – Вы хотите сказать…
>   – Я закончил, – буркнул я в трубку.
>   И Гесер, который, конечно же, слушал разговор с первого до последнего слова, немедленно отключил Эрика. Сказал:
>   **– Поздравляю, Антон. Одного из трех мы вычислили. Ты вычислил.**
>   – Спасибо за сим-карту, – ответил я. – Если бы она не искажала позиционирование – я был бы уже мертв.
>   – Вообще-то она должна придавать убедительность твоему голосу при телефонных разговорах с людьми, – сказал Гесер. – А сбой позиционирования – побочный эффект, мне никак не удается от него избавиться. Все, работай! Мы немедленно займемся Эдгаром.

.

> "Honestly, never knew his surname" - said I. - "A former employee of the Moscow Day Watch, joined the Inquisition after Igor Teplov's hearing in Prague ..."
>   "Yes, yes, yes" - Eric brightened. - "Edgar. Of course. No, we never sent him to Samarkand".
>   "Who was sent?"
>   "I don't know if you are aware, Anton," - with undisguised irony, stated Eric - " but the European Bureau of the Inquisition is is responsible for Europe. Also, for Russia, due to the duality of its geographical location. Dealing with Asia, where the country of Uzbekistan is located, is outside our power or our desire. You should contact the Asian Bureau of the Inquisition. It is currently located in Beijing. Would you like their phone number?"
>   "No, thank you," - I replied. - "And where is Edgar?"
>   "On vacation. Since ..." - followed by a short pause, - "a month ago. Anything else?"
>   **"A little advice" - I could not resist. - "Check where the Inquisitor Edgar was situated during the Edinburgh events you are aware of".**
>   "Wait, Anton!" - Eric lost his equanimity. - "Are you trying to say..."
>   "I'm done" - I growled into the phone.
>   And Geser, who, of course, was listening in to the conversation from the first to the last word, immediately disconnected Eric. He said:
>   **"Congratulations, Anton. We have figured out one of the three. *You* figured him out.**
>   "Thank you for your SIM card," - I replied. - "If it did not distort the positioning - I would be dead."
>   "Actually, it was supposed to give extra credibility to your voice during telephone conversations with people" - said Geser. - "A positioning failure was a side effect, which I still can not get rid of. All right, back to work! We will start dealing with Edgar at once."

Comment: If someone wants a translation of the quote, holla at me. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, Google Translate does a decent enough job that the quotes, and their relevance, is vaguely understandable (albeit clearly garbled).

Comment: I must have a dodgy copy of the book as there is no such scene in it. After the incident at the _chaikhana_, the next chapter begins with them travelling to the "Plateau of Demons". They pass an _aul_ along the way which has suffered from **the** recent earthquake.

Comment: @coleopterist - that's DEFINITELY a dodgy one. Get an official translation or you seem to be missing tons.

Comment: @Beofett - idiomatic translation added. Not professional translator quality, but should be adequate enough for the purpose.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Nice, thanks!  ...but now I'm going to have to dig the series out from my library and add it back to my "to read" stack, since it's been so long.